# How to concatenate two ActiveRecord queries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have simple app with a user model, role model, message model with a recipient.
A user has many messages through role 
and a role has many messages through recipients and a user also has many messages through recipients.

the recipient model has a user_id, role_id and message_id

and now i want to display all the messages of the user including his role messages and his personal message in one query. How can i accomplish this.

```
 role model

 has_many :recipients
 has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :order => 'created_at desc', through: :recipients

 user model
 has_many :roles
 has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :order => 'created_at desc', through: :roles, :uniq => true
 has_many :recipients
 has_many :private_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :order => 'created_at desc', through: :recipients

 message model
 has_many :recipients
 has_many :roles, :through => :recipients
 has_many :users, :through => :recipients
```

With all these in place how am i going to fetch the users messages both his role messages and his private messages

example

```
def all_messages
  @all_messages = current_user.#all messages scope here#
end
```

Comment: you have has_many :roles for user model. this means you have a belongs_to :user on the role model right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get all the messages is by combining the array of received_messages with the array of private_messages in the all_messages method. This will return an array of all the user's messages.

```
def all_messages
  (current_user.received_messages + current_user.private_messages).uniq
end
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks, i never new about the concat method

Comment: i tried this out and i got the following error `Cannot modify association 'User#received_messages' because it goes through more than one other association.`

Comment: Shoot, I overlooked that.  Yes, that makes sense it won't let you modify the array bc it is created through an ActiveRecord association. I just updated my answer for you.

Comment: it duplicates the messages multiple times

Comment: I tot of adding the + sign before but i was scared. I tot it was a bad practice. is it?

Comment: Nope, its just another way you can modify and work with arrays. Checkout the [Ruby API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) for other neat methods that you can use with arrays. I also edited my post once more to include `.uniq` which will remove all the duplicates in the array.